# NPE when retrieving from HashMap even though containsKey() returns true in multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, synchronization

We are trying to store unique object for a particular key. When getMyObject is called in multithreaded environment we are getting null ptr exception at the time of return statement

```
object SampleClass
{
 
    fun getMyObject(Id : String) : MyObject
    {
        if(!myMap.containsKey(Id))
        {
            synchronized(SampleClass)
            {
                if(!myMap.containsKey(Id))
                {
                    myMap[Id] = MyObject()
                }
            }
        }
        return myMap[Id]!!
    }

    private val myMap = HashMap<String,MyObject>()
}
```

It seems even though contains method returns true when we try to get the value the value is returned null.
I am not sure what is the reason behind it.

Comment: HashMap is not thread safe, so you'll have to read it and modify it while holding a lock.

Comment: This definitely does sound like a race, and you may need to synchronize the whole code block, not just one part.

Comment: This almost reads like a weird attempt at a double-checked locking mechanism. Rather than `containsKey` followed by `get` (through `[Id]`), I would just attempt a direct retrieval right away (in both cases), and check if it is `null` (assuming that the map should not contain `null` values).

Comment: Why not use `ConcurrentHashMap` and do `return myMap.computeIfAbsent(Id, k -> new  MyObject())`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the kind of trouble you get into if you try to outsmart the memory model. If you look at `HashMap`'s source, you'll find `containsKey` implemented as:

```java
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
  return getNode(key) != null;
}
```

Note that it returns true only if there's a `HashMap.Node` object corresponding to the given key. Now, this is how `get` is implemented:

```java
public V get(Object key) {
    Node<K,V> e;
    return (e = getNode(key)) == null ? null : e.value;
}
```

What you're seeing is an instance of the [unsafe publication](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/) problem. Let's say 2 threads (A & B) call `getMyObject` for a non-existent key. A is slightly  ahead of B, so it gets into the `synchronized` block before B calls `containsKey`. Particularly, A calls `put` before B calls `containsKey`. The call to `put` creates a new `Node` object and puts it into the hash map's internal data structures.

Now, consider the case when B calls `containsKey` before A exists the `synchronized` block. B *might* see the `Node` object put by A, in such case `containsKey` returns true. At this point, however, the node is unsafely published, because it is accessed by B concurrently in a non-synchronized manner. There's no guarantee its constructor (the one setting its `value` field) has been called. Even if it was called, there's no guarantee the `value` reference (or any references set by the constructor) is published along with the node reference. This means B can see an incomplete node: the node reference but not its value or any of its fields. When B proceeds to `get`, it reads `null` as the value of the unsafely published node. Hence the `NullPointerException`.

Here's an ad-hoc diagram for visualizing this:

```
         Thread A                                     Thread B
- Enter the synchronized block
  - Call hashMap.put(...)
    - Insert a new Node
                                           - See the newly inserted (but not yet 
                                             initialized from the perspective of B)
                                             Node in HashMap.containsKey
                                           - Return node.value (still null)
                                             from HashMap.get
                                           - !! throws a `NullPointerException`
    ...
- Exit the synchronized block
  (now the node is safely published)
```

The above is just one scenario where things can go wrong (see comments). To avoid such hazards, either use a `ConcurrentHashMap` (e.g. `map.computeIfAbsent(key, key -> new MyObject())`) or never access your `HashMap` concurrently outside of a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Good answer! Though in fact, it's even worse than that. For example, if one thread puts a new key into a HashMap while a second thread tries to look up a value, the second's `get()` call can enter an infinite loop and never return. (I've seen this happen in production…) They only way to avoid unexpected problems is that **_all_ access to a HashMap must be fully synchronized** — even actions that you wouldn't expect to be dangerous.

Comment: To see how things can go wrong, consider that different threads can run on different cores, each with their own memory cache. The JVM guarantees that references (and most primitives) are stored atomically — but without synchronization, there are no guarantees about when cache lines get written back to main memory, nor about how objects are distributed between cache lines. So it's entirely possible for _part_ of an object to be written back — and made visible to other threads — before the rest is…

Comment: Similarly, it's possible for one object to be written back before another, even if it was updated _after_ the other. And because a HashMap contains a large number of internal objects, it's pretty likely that they won't all be written back to main memory in the order that another thread might try to use them. So without synchronization, the internal structure of the map could be invalid in a huge range of possible ways. Going into an infinite loop is one very visible possible result, but there are many others that break in much more subtle ways.

Comment: @gidds Thanks for the insights! The above was just one scenario where things can go wrong. As you mentioned, there're many kinds of bad things that can result from the lack of ordering guarantees when things are accessed from multiple threads in a non-synchronized manner. I'd suspect the infinite loop is due to reading an incomplete linked-list/binary-tree that the HashMap stores per hash bucket.